# Unable to send more than one message from server to client and vice versa

Tags: java, networking

This is a a program in which the client and server will exchange user inputted messages to each other.
However, I am only able to send one message each to both server and client. I am not able to input anything else after that.

Client side output:

```
count is 0 ->enter message ->hi ->hello->reached 1 times
```

Server side output:

```
(port number varies)59262->count is 0->hi->enter message->hello->reached 1 times
```

I think it does not enter the for loop after the first time but i do not know why. Any help is appreciated.

Client code:

```
public class MessageClient {
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket(arg[0],Integer.parseInt(arg[1]));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
        System.out.println("count is "+count);  
        System.out.println("enter message");
        String message = scan.nextLine();
        out.println(message);
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        count++;
        System.out.println("reached "+count+" times");
        }
        while(in.readLine() != "quit");
    }catch(IOException e ) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Server code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MessageServer {
public Socket d;
public ServerSocket serverSocket;

public MessageServer() throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0); 
}

public void run() {
    BufferedReader in;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        d = serverSocket.accept();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(d.getInputStream()));
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(d.getOutputStream(),true);
        do{
        System.out.println("count is "+count);
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter message");
        String message = scan.nextLine();
        pw.println(message);
        count++;
        System.out.println("reached "+count+" times");
        }while(in.readLine()!= "quit");

    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);  
    }
}
public int getLocalPort() {
    return serverSocket.getLocalPort();
}
public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException{
    MessageServer m = new MessageServer();
    System.out.println(m.getLocalPort());
    m.run();

}
}
```

Comment: There are at least two problems with your code: a) you're using `!=` to compare strings; b) you're reading a line to check whether or not it's `"quit"` but then not storing the line for use in the next iteration.

Comment: I understand a).Thinking of using .equals method in string class now. But for b) I do not understand. Once the string is "quit", would it not just exit the loop and exit the program? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Yes, if the string is "quit" and you use equals, it will exit the program... but what if it's *not* "quit"? Presumably you want to use the non-quit value in the next iteration of the loop, to count and print out... but by then you've thrown it away.